# How combine pure functions of several slots?

Tags: pure-function

How can one define *in a functional way* a 1st-order linear differential operator involving several independent variables that can then be applied to a function of that many variables?

Consider an example with two variables, where one wants to form `D[f[x, y], x] + 3 D[f[x, y], y]` from a function `f`. Of course one could define

```
    diff[f_][x_, y_] := D[f[x, y], x] + 3 D[f[x, y], y]
```

so that for a function such as

```
    g[x_, y_] := x^2 y + Cos[x + 2 y]
```

we just evaluate:

```
    diff[g][x, y]
2 x y + 3 (x^2 - 2 Sin[x + 2 y]) - Sin[x + 2 y]   (* desired final output *)
```

But how can such an operator be defined functionally, that is, *without* explicitly using variables initially?

We could try

```
    diffOp[y_] := Derivative[1, 0][y] + 3 Derivative[0, 1][y]
```

and then

```
    diffOp[g]
3 (-2 Sin[#1 + 2 #2] + #1^2 &) + (-Sin[#1 + 2 #2] + 2 #1 #2 &)
```

But now how does one use such a combination of pure functions of several variables so as to produce the same result as from `diff[g][x,y]`?

The crux of the difficulty appears in the following simpler problem. Consider two functions of two variables:

```
    g1 = (#1^2 + #2) &
    g2 = Cos[#1 #2] &
```

How can one produce the same result as, say,

```
    g1[x, y] + 3 g2[x, y]
(* x^2 + y + 3 Cos[x y] *)
```

directly from the functional linear combination `g1 + 3 g2` -- by forming an expression of the form `oper[g1 + 3 g2][x, y]`?

By contrast with the single-variable situation, where a simple `Through` would serve as the `oper',`Through` will *not* work in the multi-variable situation here:

```
   Through[(g1 + 3 g2)[x, y]]
(* x^2 + y + (3 (Cos[#1 #2] &))[x, y] *)
```

A pure function embedded in that output.

Note that a simple sum `g1 + g2` instead of the linear combination `g1 + 3 g2`, `Through` will work (just as it does for a single variable):

```
    Through[(g1 + g2)[x, y]]
(* x^2 + y + Cos[x y] *)
```

Comment: `Through[(g1 + g2)[x, y]]`?

Comment: Your question is somewhat misleading in that even the single argument function suffers from the same problem, i.e. `Through[(f1 + 3 f2)[x]]`

Comment: Would a replacement based approach work for you, e.g. `thru[expr_[vars__]] := expr /. f_Function :> f[vars]`

Comment: @gpap: Yep, my single-argument example was *much* too simple.

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate.  Please see the linked question.  If you feel that this is not a duplicate please edit your question make that clear and flag or vote to reopen.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: This question is more general. OP wrote "more complicated algebraic, or other, combinations of the pure functions". The "or other" clause generalizes the linked question. If the OP wants to define the operations on the images by the operations on the labels, then the linked question is the answer.

Comment: I does not seem a duplicate to me, either. The other question is expressly limited to a specific combination of functions. (er, not linear, but... that one)

Comment: @Peltio The answers however are not, at least at a glance.  Did you try them?

Comment: @Hector "or other" has yet to be clarified, and I expect to see an example where the methods in the answers fail before I reopen this question to address it.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard Er.. no. But looking at the question I was not even tempted to. So, perhaps it would be better to either merge or edit the original question in order to reflect this. Semantically of syntactically duplicate? That is the question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: The operation $(x\mapsto f(x)) \mapsto (x\mapsto f(0))$ creates a new function out of $f$. The linked question breaks in this case.

Comment: @Peltio We can certainly address that after I ascertain murray's requirements.  By the way, though the title says "\[duplicate\]" you should note that the actual header added to the question reads: "This question already has an answer here:"

Comment: @Hector rather than using formal notation why don't you show me what you mean with *Mathematica* code?  Anyway, I'll be leaving soon but you can always extend your answer in the mean time if you have something to add; we can organize things later.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: `f[x : _Function | _Symbol] := Function @@ {{s}, x[0]}` defines a function that acts on functions and produces functions yet it cannot be represented as an operation on the label alone.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard - Perhaps I do not understand what happens to a closed duplicate question. But if it disappears, it is the original question that needs to be amended to reflect the greater generality of the answers. Otherwise, newcomers will be tempted to ask the more general question again and again.

Comment: Please reopen so I can explain the source of the problem and perhaps get a useful answer!

Comment: Murray, I'd be happy to reopen, but are you sure that the linked question doesn't answer your question as well? If you use `Through2` from VF1's answer (in the duplicate), then your first example is correctly solved as `Through2[(g1 + 3 g2)[x, y]]`. As for your `diffOp`, if you define it as `Through2[(Derivative[1, 0][y] + 3 Derivative[0, 1][y])[##]] &`, then `diffOp[g][x, y]` gives the same answer as `diff[g][x,y]`, which seems like what you wanted.

Comment: OK, `Through2` does the trick. Much more complicated than I had hoped! *Mathematica* just doesn't really "like" functions (in the ordinary sense) as first-class objects, in contrast to the way modern math treats them as such. No need to reopen. This trail through my question above and to the solution of the linked duplicate will, I hope, help others (and me, when I forget how to do it!).

Comment: @Peltio "duplicate" questions may or may not be deleted.  Frequently they are left visible expressly provide people another way to find the original question and its answers.  I agree that the original question can and should be edited to make it better illustrate the power of the answers received.  (FYI: You can make this edit yourself if you like; it will be reviewed and either approved or rejected by other members.)

Comment: @murray You said "please reopen so I can explain the source of the problem ..." -- you can edit your question to better explain it even when it is closed, and in fact that is the *expected procedure*: close question with some form of problem or uncertainty; wait for edit; reopen if appropriate.  Only if your question is Locked or Deleted will you not be able to edit it.  In the end I'm glad you have a solution.  You too might consider editing the original to include your problem class.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I just heavily edited (actually, completely rewrote) the question so as to start with the actual context, so that it might usefully lead future readers to the question of which it's been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: It would be desirable to change the original subject of the question to something like: "How define functionally a linear differential operator in several variables?" But I don't have the ability to do that; I presume a Moderator can.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematics, you can define new functions using operation on their images. Your example, $g_1+3 g_2$ is effectively defined as the function $x\mapsto g_1(x)+3g_2(x)$. Mathematicians use the following notation for functions:

[image]

The $f$ before the semicolon is just a label.

In Mathematica, an assignment such as `g1 = (#1^2 + #2) &` introduces the label $g1$ but more importantly it creates the rule $( \#1, \#2 )\mapsto \#1^2+\#2$.

Paraphrasing your question: how can we create, out of $\#\#\mapsto g1(\#\#)$ and $\#\#\mapsto g2(\#\#)$, a new rule $\#\#\mapsto whateverLabel(\#\#)$ without explicitly giving $whateverLabel(\#\#)$ yet keeping it rather arbitrary.

Some operations on functions, (such as multiplication by a number $α f$), have a natural meaning in terms of the images of the functions; but natural is not the same as nonexistent. And in the end, you need to have the equivalent of the line $x\mapsto α f(x)$.

Therefore, your quest is impossible. You could, for example, limit your quest and keep the operations limited to a small subset (sums of functions, multiplication by a number, multiplication of functions). In that case, we might be able to help.

---

PS. Think twice before replying that one could define the operations on the images by the operations on the labels.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, this is too long to fit into a comment) A possible workaround is to use fresh unevaluated symbols to represent your expression of free functions

```
expr = 3 f1 + 2Exp[-f2]

g1 = (#1^2 + #2) &;
g2 = Cos[#1 #2] &;
```

This will produce a list with the functions of said variables.

```
funlist = {g1, g2}; arglist = {x, y};
dummylist = {f1, f2};
funrule = #@(Sequence @@ arglist) & /@ funlist
```

> {x^2+y, Cos[x y]}

Then you can use a replacement rule, as suggested in one of the comments:

```
expr /. Thread[dummylist -> funrule]
```

> 3(x^2+y) + 2 Exp[-Cos[x y]

You might automate this into a procedure that could generate the unique identifiers by parsing an unevaluated (held) `expr` so that when you pass expr[g1,g2], you'll end up with expr[f1,f2] in the body of the procedure.