# Combining pure functions

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style, pure-function

Is there an easy way to combine pure functions into a single pure function?  For example, say I have

```
f = #1^2 &;
g = #1 - 2 &;
```

and I want to define a new pure function `h` that is the difference of the two functions (as currently defined, so that `h` will not change if `f` or `g` are redefined).  `h = f - g` doesn't work because it doesn't combine them into a single function.  The best I've been able to come up with is

`h = Evaluate[f@# - g@#] &`

but this seems a bit hack-ish.  Is there a more natural way to combine them?

**Edit:** I was looking for something where Mathematica performs its automatic simplifications, just as if we'd had `f = x^2; g = x - 2; h = f - g`, but for pure functions.

Comment: Why not simply `#1^2 + #1 - 2 &` ?  And see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33112/how-combine-pure-functions-of-several-slots

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Well of course if the functions are known and this short, then you can just define the combined function manually. But I want to be able to handle the case where the functions are unknown and/or extremely complicated.

Comment: `h = f@# + g@# &`?

Comment: @wxffles This is a step in the right direction, but not really what I want because it leaves the functions unevaluated and sensitive to later changes in their definitions. I edited the question to incorporate your suggestion (since mine original version doesn't work for subtraction), but I was really wondering if there was a way to eliminate the `Evaluate`.  Probably not, and now the code seems more natural, so if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Wanting `h` to not be affected by later changes to `f` and `g` is an important point you should put in the question.

Comment: With `f + g` you can use `h = Through @* (f+g)`, but with `-` the issue is that `f` and `g` are a bit deeper inside the expression tree (since `f-g` is really `Plus[f, Times[g, -1]]`).

Comment: Related: [Distributing function arguments with function compositions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92269/14303)

Comment: Nearly a duplicate: [(87985)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87985/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think that question has a very different focus from mine and is only superficially related.

Comment: I'd say the relation is more than superficial but you'll note that I neither closed this nor suggested that others vote to do so. :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is a solution for the simplest case.

Not meant to prevent evaluation (except of the components' functions bodies).

It only works with `expressions with slots &` kind of pure functions etc. So it won't merge named arguments or resolve attributes from `Function`.

```
mergeF[expr_] := Function @@ (Hold[expr] /. Function[body_] :> body)

  (* or Replace[Function[expr], Function[body_] :> body, {1, -1}]*)

mergeF[(f - g)/Exp[g]]
```

[image]

If don't need to care at all you can drop `Hold`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `With`:

```
h = With[{f = f, g = g},  f[#] - g[#] &]
```

Comment: It will work but it is not the same as OP's `h`

Comment: @Kuba I'm not sure what you mean.  His use of `Evaluate` accomplishes nothing, but the use of `With` achieves what he was asking for (i.e., eliminates the appearance of `f` and `g` in the own values of `h`, as he requested in his comments).

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean too :) this is what OP's `h` is: `2 - #1 + #1^2 &` and this is what is yours: `(#1^2 &)[#1] - (#1 - 2 &)[#1] &`. Of course `Evaluate` does its job there.

Comment: @Kuba On `Evaluate`: right, I see what he did.  (I had thought he evaluated the function expression, not just the argument.)  On the difference: does it make a difference?  Hmm, I suppose `Evaluate` could lead to simplifications, avoiding the need to recompute them every call.  So then, was using `Evaluate` that way a good solution after all?  I thought using `With` was the standard answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say one way is better than another unless OP narrows the case. As you noticed your solution prevents simplifications/evaluation, which is reasonable choice.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that I want Mathematica to perform its automatic simplifications.