# Folow-up on combining pure functions

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, pure-function

This is a follow-up to [this question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/142072/combining-pure-functions) Consider:

```
f = #^2&
g = #^3&

Compose[f, g]
(#1^3 &)^2
```

Am I the only one to think this is a bug?

Comment: Note that `Compose[f, g]` does return `f[g]`, and that `Compose[]` has been obsolete for quite a while...

Comment: `Composition[f, g][x]` evaluates to `x^6`

Comment: While that question is different, the answer explains the difference. We could close it as a duplicate then instead of as a simple mistake. [Is there a name for #1@#2&?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28778/5478) Let me know.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that is very relevant. I have no strong opinion on duplicate vs not, so leave it to you.

Comment: @IgorRivin thanks. Duplicates are never deleted while simple mistakes can be, unless they have a positive score.