# Pure function slot delivery

Tags: pure-function, slot

Another novice problem encountered. I am going to need a cardiology surgery. :(

For a simple example,

```
a = #1 &;
b = #2 &;
f = a^2 + b^2;
f
```

results in

```
(#1 &)^2 + (#2 &)^2
```

However, my goal is

```
(#1 )^2 + (#2 )^2
```

I know it can be done as

```
f=(#1)^2+(#2)^2
```

But still, substitution is necessary in my work, which means the step of `a` and `b` cant be neglected.

So what do I miss? Thanks:)

Comment: This is doable, e.g. `f =  Evaluate[a[#^2] + b[Null,#2^2]]&`, but the fact that things have gotten so messy for something so simple is a sign that you're approaching whatever you want to do in the wrong way. What's wrong with not binding anything to `a` and `b` and then using a `ReplaceAll` or something?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: [142072](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/142072/5478), do you agree?